# how can I reversely iterate on an aurelia array repeater?

Tags: javascript, arrays, aurelia

I am trying to iterate from the end of an array to the beginning of it.

For example:

repeater-template.js:

```
export class RepeaterTemplate {
constructor() {
this.friends = [
  'Alice',
  'Bob',
  'Carol',
  'Dana'
  ];
 }
}
```

repeater-template.html:

```
 <template>
   <p repeat.for.reverse ="friend of friends">Hello, ${friend}!</p>
 </template>
```

output:

```
Hello Dana
Hello Carol
Hello Bob
Hello Alice
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the accepted solution will work if the array mutates. I believe the ideal is to create a value-converter that returns the reversed array without mutating the original one. For instance:

JS

```
export class App {
  message = 'Hello World!';

  friends = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

  attached() {
    //MUTATE!
    setTimeout(() => { this.friends.push('d') }, 300);
  }
}

export class ReverseValueConverter {
  toView(array) {
    return array.slice().reverse();
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<p repeat.for="friend of friends | reverse">Hello, ${friend}!</p>
```

Running example: https://gist.run/?id=20d00a205e651b6b4d7064e2f57d2675

---

We can't use a computed-property here because `@computedFrom` doesn't support collections yet https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/249.

Another possible solution is subscribing the array via BindingEngine and updating a reversed copy when it mutates, but that would be too much code to solve a simple problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you explain why the `slice()` call is needed?

Comment: The `slice()` is needed to "copy" the array. Otherwise, the real array would be mutated.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Aurelia doesn't have any explicit functions for this, but you could make a simple function in the viewmodel:

```
reverse(arr) {
    return arr.slice().reverse();
}
```

Then in the view:

```
<template>
   <p repeat.for="friend of reverse(friends)">Hello, ${friend}!</p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Or `<p repeat.for ="friend of Array.prototype.reverse.call(friends)">Hello, ${friend}!</p>`

Comment: @FabioLuz - My answer was a shortcut. The full code is to add e.g. `this.friends = Array.prototype.reverse.call(this.friends);` in the constructor, and then `<p repeat.for ="friend of friends">Hello, ${friend}!</p>` as `repeat.for` expects the list to be a class property..

Thank you - I should have replied more accurately.